# Region Undefined in Backbone Layout

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm having a major issue with Backbone Marionette that I just can't seem to figure out. Maybe my man Derick Bailey can help me out.
What I'm doing is simple, at least one would think.
I have a layout (please ignore the improper coffee indenting for now).

```
class SearchLayout extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout

# template: _.template SearchResultsTemplate
template: Handlebars.compile SearchResultsTemplate
tagName: "section"
className: "search-layout"

ui:
  "searchInput":  ".search-input"
  "saveTopic":    ".save-this-topic"

regions:
  resourcesRegion: ".resources-content"
```

And later on I bind to a model that's tied to this layout, a `@searchResults` model.

```
initialize: ->
  @model.on "change:query", @setClasses, @
  @model.on "change:query", @setResource, @

onRender: ->
  # app.vent.trigger "view:rendered"
  setTimeout =>
    @setClasses()
    @globalBindings()
    @handlebarsHelpers()
    @bindUIElements()
  , 50

handlebarsHelpers: ->
  # helpers specific to this view.

globalBindings: ->
  # @model.on "change:query", @setResource, @

setResource: ->

  @resources = new ResourcesCollection()
  @resources.fetch
    async: false
    success: =>
      @view = new ResourcesViews.collectionView
        collection: @resources
      @resourcesRegion.show @view
```

I tried at first to bind to my resources with `.on` but that wasn't working well, so I decided to go with a success on fetch as shown here.

The strange thing is I had it working great, and it even renders (sometimes) the first time, but after I make any changes to my search model, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined
```

Here are my views:

```
define [
  "backbone.marionette"
  "jquery"
  "underscore"
  "backbone"
  "text!templates/resources/resource.html"
], (Marionette, $, _, Backbone, ResourceViewTemplate) ->
  class ResourceView extends Marionette.ItemView

    className: "js-resource js-resource-view col-md-6"
    tagName: "div"
    template: Handlebars.compile ResourceViewTemplate

    initialize: ->

    onBeforeRender: ->

    onRender: ->

  class ResourcesEmptyView extends Marionette.ItemView

    className: "js-resource-not-found not-found js-resource-view col-md-12"
    tagName: "section"
    template: "<h3>Sorry, nothing found for that search. Try another.</h3>"

    initialize: ->

    onBeforeRender: ->

    onRender: ->

  class ResourcesCollectionView extends Marionette.CollectionView

    className: "js-resources js-resources-view list-unstyled"
    tagName: "ul"
    emptyView: ResourcesEmptyView
    itemView: ResourceView

    initialize: ->

    onBeforeRender: ->

    onRender: ->

  exports =
    collectionView: ResourcesCollectionView
    individualView: ResourceView
```

The strange thing is, my `@view.render().el` is actually defined and working great! It will even append to the `$('body')` with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out!

Turns out, I needed to re-render the region, then call `@setResources` on my `onRender` method. I'm not entirely sure why it was getting undefined, but here's what ended up working:

```
initialize: ->
  @model.on "change:query", @setClasses, @
  @model.on "change:query", @render, @

onRender: ->
  console.log 'render'
  # app.vent.trigger "view:rendered"
  setTimeout =>
    @setClasses()
    @globalBindings()
    @handlebarsHelpers()
    @bindUIElements()
    @setResource()
  , 50

handlebarsHelpers: ->
  # helpers specific to this view.

globalBindings: ->
  # @model.on "change:query", @setResource, @

setResource: ->
  console.log 'setting resource'

  @resources = new ResourcesCollection
    searchQuery: @model.get("query")
  @resources.fetch
    async: false
    success: =>
      @view = new ResourcesViews.collectionView
        collection: @resources
      console.log @resourcesRegion
      @resourcesRegion.show @view
```